# How to induce Mandela effect to the entire nation that machines are uprising?

Tags: psychology, robots, brain, memory

Set in the 18th century C.E. somewhere in Europe with population of slightly more than 2 million, they are just starting to light up the streets using electricity and for the first time they gets to enjoy chilled canned drinks in the heat.

The human brain is simply too amazing at designing and creating wonders, unfortunately a coin has 2 sides and our brain also suffers from some shortcomings such as unreliable memories.

I wonder how is it possible for the entire nation to think that they are being attacked by machines which have never existed in the first place at all? My target is to have at least 50% of the population be under this Mandela effect for a trial period of 3 months.

Comment: I am confused: what has to do the first half of your post with the second, and an entire nation is not 50% of the population

Comment: What is the "Mandela effect"? Do you refer to Winnie Mandela? There was no electric light anywhere in Europe in the 18th century; end of the 19th at the earliest. Ice was available in Europe looooong before the 18th century.

Comment: The Mandela effect is a phenomenon which primarily affects memory, it involves mass fake memories. It's not something that can be used to have people believe they're under attack by robots. This question doesn't seem like it was researched well.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot that people in Europe have been burning witches for centuries despite nobody having really seen any witchcraft, or persecuting minorities based on unverified rumors heard through the grapevine.

This is the very same case. Just spread a rumor based on something remotely concrete, like a clockwork killing a man, have it inflated until it becomes a mass hysteria and most of your population will believe it.